# Convert data from table to table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I was working in a project which is converting some data to another table by an online API (web service), so the plan is fetching data from the API and converting the prices to another table, I still got the same error again and again which is not convert each row as the way I need.
SCREENSHOT : [THE UI TO UNDERSTAND THE USE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TbHS.png) 
CODE :

```
function Send_Button() {

  //activate the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cellCurrency = spreadsheet.getRange('E9').getValues();

  //fatching the data from the API
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="+cellCurrency).getContentText();

  //parsing data to JSON
  var json = JSON.parse(res);

  //exporting data in variables
  var USD=json['rates']['USD'],
      CAD=json['rates']['CAD'],
      GBP=json['rates']['GBP'],
      EUR=json['rates']['EUR'];

  //an array to fetch just 4 currencies
  var CRN = [USD,CAD,GBP,EUR];
  var cellsPrice = spreadsheet.getRange('E5:E8').getValues();

  //targeted cell in the second currencies table
    var cellsTraget1 = spreadsheet.getRange('H3:K3');
    var cellsTraget2 = spreadsheet.getRange('H4:K4');
    var cellsTraget3 = spreadsheet.getRange('H5:K5');
    var cellsTraget4 = spreadsheet.getRange('H6:K6');

//converting process
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {

    cellsTraget1.setValue(cellsPrice[0]*CRN[0]);
    cellsTraget2.setValue(cellsPrice[1]*CRN[1]);
    cellsTraget3.setValue(cellsPrice[2]*CRN[2]);
    cellsTraget4.setValue(cellsPrice[3]*CRN[3]);

  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating but not using the iterator variable i, is that correct? Perhaps writing the code in a more readable way with first getting the rows and then the cell value for each column and then iterating over both row and column would make it more readable and makes you find the issue faster.

Comment: I will try that, until somone gives me the right direction, thanks any way

Comment: You are using `i` in your for loop. What's up with that? Why do you need a loop then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your `var cellCurrency` is the correct range you want?
From your screenshot it appears the right cell is "E10"... but let's assume you fixed that.

Then you have an issue with your array dimensions, your `var cellsPrice` is a 2D array (Rows, Columns) even if the range you are getting values from is only one row!.

Another issue, your `var cellsTraget*` is also a 2D Range, so you can't use [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))... You could use [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) but the values array **MUST** match the range's dimension. And as they currently are, they don't match. *Hint: transpose them if you want to use said function*.

Apart from that, your for-loop makes no sense at all, since you are not looping anyhow!.

### Here is some sample working code:

```js
function sendButton() {
  
  // Activate the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var baseCurrency = "USD";
  
  // Fetching the data from the API
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base="+baseCurrency).getContentText();
  
  // Parsing data to JSON
  var json = JSON.parse(res);
  
  // Exporting data in variables
  var USD = [json['rates']['USD'], json['rates']['CAD'], json['rates']['GBP'], json['rates']['EUR']];
  
  // I will do it for one row
  var articlePrice = spreadsheet.getRange('E5').getValue();
  
  // Mind the array's dimensions!
  var convertedPricesRange = spreadsheet.getRange('I5:L5');
  var convertedPriceValues = [[articlePrice*USD[0],articlePrice*USD[1],articlePrice*USD[2],articlePrice*USD[3]]];
  
  // Set converted values
  convertedPricesRange.setValues(convertedPriceValues);
}
```

#### Further reading:

- Sheets Class [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html)